# Using \eqref with RefTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

How can I open the equation selection buffer in RefTeX automatically when entering `\eqref` in Emacs? I have the following line in my `.emacs` file

```
(setq reftex-label-alist '((nil ?e nil "~\\eqref{%s}" nil nil)))
```

But this does not seem to work as I hoped
([http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/reftex](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/reftex/Using-_005ceqref.html))..
Now, entering `\eqref` and then pressing enter, will just insert an empty
`\eqref{}` into the buffer. What I would like to happen is the equation selection buffer in RefTeX to be opened, after which I will be able to choose the label to reference from that buffer..

(Note that entering `\ref` (not `\eqref`) works as expected, that is, first I get a question: "Label type: [ efinNst]" and after having chosen the type, the selection buffer is opened)

I am using GNU Emacs version 23.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

My `.emacs` init file is

```
(setq TeX-electric-escape t)
(setq reftex-label-alist '((nil ?e nil "~\\eqref{%s}" nil nil)))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
```

Consider the sample file `t.tex`

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:1}  
  1+1=2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Running `emacs t.tex` produces the following in the Emacs message buffer:

```
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs23/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...
Loading /usr/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp/auctex.el (source)...done
Loading /usr/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp/preview-latex.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs23/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50emacs-goodies-el.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50latex-cjk-common.el (source)...
Loading cjk-enc...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50latex-cjk-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50latex-cjk-thai.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50lilypond-data.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50magit.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50octave3.2-emacsen.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50org-mode.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50psvn.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50thailatex.el (source)...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Automatic display of crossref information was turned on
Applying style hooks... done
Sorting environment...
Removing duplicates... done
```

Comment: If you use AUCTeX `C-c ) e` does the trick, without even writing `\eqref`.

Comment: Yes that works fine.. Thank you! (Is it possible to get the other method (in my question) also to work?)

Comment: I don't know, on my Emacs that works as you expect.  You should give more information about your configuration.

Comment: I see.. I updated my question with information about my configuration..

Comment: Just to understand: `C-c ) e` works but `C-c C-m eqref RET` doesn't word?  Is `C-c C-m eqref RET` at least able to autocomplete with known citation keys?

Comment: Yes `C-c C-m eqref RET` does not work.. That is, it produces an empty `\eqref{}` in the buffer.. What do you mean by autocomplete citation keys? (`C-c C-m cite RET` works fine..)

Comment: I mean that you're able to automatically complete using `TAB`.  To fix your problem, if you haven't done yet, you have to plug RefTeX into AUCTeX putting this in your init file: `(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)`.

Comment: Ok:) Thanks for helping me out. At least, I already have the line `(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)` in my `.emacs` file.. So that should be fine..

Comment: And still doesn't work?  If so, in menu `Ref > Options`, is `AUCTeX interface` ticked off?

Comment: Yes it is ticked off..

Comment: Ok, last attempt: check whether `amsmath` is in `TeX-active-styles`: `C-h v TeX-active-styles RET`.  Issue this command while in the offended buffer.

Comment: yes `amsmath` is there..

Comment: I can't understand, that should work! `:-(`

Comment: Ok:) I agree that this is a difficult case.. At least, I will use your first suggestion `C-c ) e`.. Thanks again :)

Comment: @giordano I have updated my question with more information..

Comment: That is the only code you have on `.emacs`?

Comment: yes :) I removed everything else to debug..

Comment: Try adding `(setq TeX-auto-parse t)`.  Did you install Emacs and AUCTeX from Ubuntu repository?

Comment: Adding `(setq TeX-auto-parse t)` has no effect.. and I did not install Emacs myself since my laptop is owned by my company.. so unfortunately, I do not know how it was installed..

Comment: which version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: Emacs 24.3 and AUCTeX 11.87, last stable version of both.  Here all works as you expect with your configuration, I still can't find out what's wrong with your system.  In the past, I've used Emacs 23 from Ubuntu 12.04, I had no problem with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I think I will try to install Emacs version 24 tomorrow and see if that solves the issue..

Comment: I hope so `:-)`

Comment: Another attempt.  While in the buffer of `t.tex` check the value of `TeX-style-hook-list`: `C-h v TeX-style-hook-list RET`.  It should be quite long.  Search for `eqref`.  You should find `("eqref" TeX-arg-ref)`.  Assure that `eqref` appears only once.  If so, that **has to work** because `TeX-arg-ref` is the same function used by `\ref` and you say that `\ref` works for you.

Comment: @giordano I cannot find `("eqref" TeX-arg-ref)` in the `TeX-style-hook-list` list.. there is entries for the following style names : t, dvipdfm, dvipdf, psfrag, dvips, pst-pdf, pdftricks, pdftex, latex2, latex2e, and LATEX

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9216/discussion-between-giordano-and-hakon-haegland)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to override possible other `eqref` macro definitions, you should add a dummy `(ignore)` to the definition of the macro.  This code, in your `.emacs`, does the trick:

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (TeX-add-symbols '("eqref" TeX-arg-ref (ignore)))))
```